# Laravel routing to <ResourceController>.destroy from an input form (in *.blade.php) using ResourceController

Tags: php, rest, crud, laravel-5.4

I have a database table, each row have a primary key called **id**. I want to make a page to delete the row which **id** is submitted with the Form below:

```
<form action="{{ route('Account.destroy') }}" method="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <button type="submit"> Delete My Account </button>
</form>
```

but the Form didn't work as expected!

[I got these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYiGL.png)

I found out that I need to conduct the id to **{{ route() }}**, so i tried **{{ route('['Account.destroy', id]')** and then these errors appeared:

[The errors' page with conducted **id** to **route()**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aa1M.png)

I know it's wrong method at **route(['Account.destroy', id])** but i don't have any idea to fix this. Please help me! Thank you!

P/s: Sorry if my English was too bad!

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the second one. You need something like this:

```
{{ route('Account.destroy', ['account' => $id]) }}
```

See [this section of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

@Samsquanch is right. additionally, the form's method should be 'POST' and add the following line inside the form:

`<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"/>`

Comment: Thanks. But it's still working when i t use a normal controller declare with route